# Setting up MinGW in Windows 7 to compile adequately portable C++ code

Tags: windows, compilation, path, mingw

**Preface**: I have been really turned away from writing and learning C/C++ in Visual Studios and Windows with the way things are compiled and worked with. I much prefer Ubuntu with vim and g++ but I want to have In addition to that a good Windows based work environment set up.

**Question**: Basically I am learning C++ with Notepad++ and looked into MinGW to be my compiler. I am having a hard time finding good answers on to how best go setting it up, and all the minutia involved in compiling code, and how it becomes dependent on MinGW's dll files.

It seems I have to set up Paths to compile outside of the C:\MinGW\bin folder, but even then I am forced to execute the program in that very same folder. Otherwise I get an error that I am missing a dll.

While not only is this a hassle for actual development(don't say move to Linux, read the pre-face) but It prevents my code from having any sort of portability to other windows systems. Perhaps I lack knowledge on how to correctly create executables and package their files with installers. If thats what I need to learn then perhaps point me in the right direction.

Comment: *"but even then I am forced to execute the program in that very same folder"* -- By "very same folder", are you referring to C:\MinGW\bin, or do you mean the folder you compiled the executable in?

Comment: I suggest you follow the documentation: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes that is the folder I am talking about.

Comment: Your statement is completely ambiguous with regards to my question.  Which folder is "that"?  Read my question again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know, It honestly didn't help me much. I don't exactly know how those things influence my C++ environment. And like I said I'm mostly concerned with how it affects the portability of my code. Running things out of MinGW\bin isn't the biggest problem for just mocking up some test code.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley My apologies. I mean MinGW\Bin. Outside of that folder the executable throws a "missing dll" error. When inside bin however it does indeed work. This is an undesirable dependency for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do for your exe to work is either put the GCC DLLs somewhere in PATH (by adding `C:\MinGW\bin` to your PATH) or compile all your code to link statically to the GCC runtime DLLs by using "-static" as a linker argument. When you distribute your executable, you'll need to make sure libgcc*.dll and libstdc++-6.dll are both installed alongside your executable. (if you're still using MinGW.org's toolchain, time to step up to MinGW-w64, who don't have a `mingwm10.dll` or whatever it's called).

The GCC DLLs are much the same as Visual Studio's C++ redistributables; to run code built with a certain VS version, you need the DLLs. Linking statically is the only way to not have that problem.

Also, get a cross-platform build system like CMake. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Oh wow, this is incredibly helpful thank you. For someone that has mostly worked in Java and Python, understanding just what goes on and how components of a program get linked is a bit hard to wrap your head around at first. When a redistributable is installed is it being added to your systems path then? In order to any program that needs it to be able to reach out to it?

Comment: @Aerlusch: Windows uses a nifty magic system called winsxs (at least before msvcr100, don't know what exactly changed, but something did) to regulate all the different msvcr* versions. In short, yes: all programs that require the msvcrNNN.dll file(s) should work after the redistributable is installed. And you then don't have to care about copying C runtime DLLs yourself. The redistributables only apply to MSVC, not MinGW GCC though.

Answer (score 2):

Download the [nuwen distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) of mingw. Install with the installer. That will create (among other things) a file named `open_distro_window.bat`. Create a shortcut to that on your desktop. Double click it, and it'll open a window with the path and other environment variables set up so you can compile, link, etc. (in whatever directory you choose).

To make life easiest, once you've created your shortcut, right-click and edit its properties -- change the "start in" directory to the root of wherever you keep projects you're developing.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it will help a lot.

Comment: "Thank you, that's helpful" is usually expressed (on this site) by clicking the triangle above the big zero (to the left) and/or the checkmark outline below it.

Comment: I can't vote up your comment since I just made this account, and don't have the adequate reputation. I didn't know about the check mark, but that seems to not be working for me either. Don't worry, I'm not trying to rob you of your precious rep points. ;)

Comment: @Aerlusch: It's not that I care about the rep points, but that votes and accepts on answers help others find which answers were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: `I much prefer Ubuntu with vim and g++` .
I now use a long time "msys / mingw" and am happy.

MSYS is a **collection of GNU utilities** such as **bash**, make, gawk and grep to allow building of applications and programs which depend on traditionally **UNIX tools** to be present.

It is intended to supplement MinGW and the deficiencies of the cmd shell.[Read more MSYS / minGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS). Put your sources in the `c:\msys\1.0\src` folder there, they are put in the right.

I tried it too, a long time ago with "cygwin". Had it always one or the other problem.

Comment: Ok I wasn't entirely sure what MSYS would offer me. It seems this or Cygwin would be very useful for giving me a desirable development environment. I'll look more into it. \n\n Honestly I think my biggest concern is how my executable becomes very dependent on the MinGW's dll files and being correctly pathed to work properly.

Comment: msys is only the **bash** and with minGW together creates perfect MinGW's dll files.